# Chromatic index of complete graphs using line graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm interested in computing $\chi'(K_n)$ from the relation
$$\chi'(K_n)=\chi(L(K_n)),$$
where $L$ denotes the line graph operator. Is there a good argument to do this?

(The answer is of course $=n-1$ for even $n$ and $=n$ for odd $n$)